# How to take input from user and save that into other file

Tags: php

I want to take input from user and save that into other file while keepping current data. 
I want to take below details from user

```
server type : cpanel , FTP , windows , other (drop down)
Hostname 
Username
Password
```

And save that in backup.php file. In backup php file I already have format

```
<?php
include xmlapi.php
$hostname= "";
$username = "";
$password = "  ";
?>
```

I want details provided by user in this file. I can generare php file to ask these details but not sure how to insert data in backup.php while keeping existing data

can I get some help on it ?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your current code for producing the file (and getting the additional data, if you have it).

Comment: This is a horrible idea. Please have another think about what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this config :

```
<?php
include xmlapi.php
$hostname = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
?>
```

This will write user submitted data to that file :

```
<?php
$filename = "backup.php";
$user_data = $_POST; // contains $_POST['hostname'], $_POST['username'], etc
if(file_exists($filename))
{
    $error_line = '';
    foreach ($user_data as $config_name => $new_value)
    {
        $out = '';
        $file = fopen($filename,'r+');
        while(!feof($file))
        {
            $line = fgets($file);
            $pattern_open = preg_match('/\$'.$config_name.'[ ]*=\s/i', $line, $matches_open);
            $pattern_close = preg_match('/;.*\n/i', $line, $matches_close);
            $out .= $matches_open != FALSE ? $matches_open[0] . "'" . $new_value . "'" . $matches_close[0] : $line;
        }
        fclose($file);
        if (!file_put_contents($filename, $out))
        {
            if ($config_name === key($user_data))
            {
                $error_line .= "$config_name";
            }
            else
            {
                $error_line .= "$config_name, ";
            }
        }
    }
    if ($error_line != NULL)
    {
        echo 'Error at line : ' . $error_line;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Config saved';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'File not found!';
}
```